# Gravity Forms and Authorize.net Feed

Tags: wordpress, authorize.net, gravity-forms-plugin, applepay

Is there a way to add additional items to the Authorize.net feed?

For example, on the feed page, the only options are the required Authorize.net fields for payment:

- Billing Information

  - Payment Amount
  - Email
  - Address
  - Address 2
  - City
  - State
  - Zip
  - Country
  - Phone

I would like to add some information to the transaction that is processed and sent to Authorize.net. For example, (as found in the [Authorize.net API docs](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#payment-transactions))

- Profile

  - Create Profile
- Order

  - InvoiceNumber
  - Description

It would also be awesome if I could also integrate with Authorize.nets new ApplePay API this way. I am comfortable adding/modifying code and would prefer if this functionality added fields or some sort of GUI in the Authorize.net settings page of the Gravity Forms backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gravity Forms documentation explains how to write your own addon using their payment addon framework. It's actually not that difficult. My first time, I used the authorize.net addon as a guide.
https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gfpaymentaddon/
Otherwise open up the authorize.net addon and look for hooks you may can tie into to do what you want. There are a few but I've not used them. Search for do_action and apply_filters.
I should also mention that you can add to the feed using hooks but just adding to the feed will not send the data to A.net. You would still have to write the code to get the new feed data and do something with it.

Comment: Thank you! I will dig into the documentation. I didn't even realize those pages had that information.